# Radio Button Losing Focus After Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, focus

I am having an issue with posting back after selecting an option in a radio button.
After "yes" is selected, it must post back to load a text box beneath; however, if no is selected, the text box must not appear.

I had found a solution to other post back issues across my site at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17571/Maintain-focus-between-postbacks-in-ASP-NET-2-0-al (I added radio button the list of "CurrentControl is "'s), but for a reason beyond myself, it doesn't seem to apply to radio buttons.

As I have just created my account, I can't post pictures yet, but when the page posts back, the focus is shifted to the last text box or drop down list that has been focused.

**Aspx for Radio Button:**

```
<table class="dataentry">
     <tr>
          <td class="column1">
               <asp:Label ID="lblPrevEmployed" runat="server" Text="Have you ever been employed by our company?"meta:resourcekey="lblPrevEmployed"></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td class="column2">
               <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoPrevEmployed_Yes" runat="server" GroupName="PrevEmployed" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="rdoPrevEmployed_OnCheckedChanged" Text="Yes" meta:resourcekey="rbPrevEmployedYes" /> &nbsp;
               <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoPrevEmployed_No" runat="server" GroupName="PrevEmployed" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="rdoPrevEmployed_OnCheckedChanged" Text="No" meta:resourcekey="rbPrevEmployedNo" />
               <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvPrevEmployed" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must select either Yes or No." ValidationGroup="Group" OnServerValidate="cvPrevEmployed_ServerValidate" Display="Dynamic" meta:resourcekey="cvPrevEmployed"></asp:CustomValidator>
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
(I've used a RadioButtonList instead of individual RadioButtons)

One div is for the radio button list and the second div is for displaying the description associated with the selected radio button.

Also a notification label will be enabled (which would be disabled by default) with a message.

[HTML]

```
<asp:Label ID="NotifyLabel" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
<br />
<div id="SelAccTypeSelect" runat="server" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Account Type 1" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Account Type 2" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
<div id="SelAccTypeDesc" runat="server" style="width: 920px;"></div>
```

The is an array containing the available descriptions that correspond to the value of the radio buttons.

[CODE BEHIND]

```
private void InitializeSelAccTypeDesc()
{
SelAcctDescription[0] = "<p>This account type is for users who want to do something like this.</p>";
SelAcctDescription[1] = "<p>This account type is for other users who want to do something like that.</p>";
}

protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// get the selected account type
AccTypeByte = Convert.ToByte(RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString());

      // notify the user with the value of the selected radio button
NotifyLabel.Visible = true;
NotifyLabel.Text = string.Format("{0} was the value selected.   -   ", AccTypeByte);

// replace the html in the div with the html from the selected array element
SelAccTypeDesc.InnerHtml = SelAcctDescription[Convert.ToInt32(AccTypeByte)];
}
```

*NOTE: 0 could be 'No' and 1 could be 'Yes'
You can add an if statement around the NotifyLabel, to only show based on the value of AccTypeByte.

Comment: Is there any way I can see your code in context? I feel like this may apply to what I'm doing, but I'm currently unclear as to what the code behind is really doing for the focus. Thanks for the response!